# onclick on a spinner?

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

Hy,i need to have an onclick on a spinner.
This is my spinner:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnTarghe);
final String targhe[]=risposta.split("/");
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
        targhe
        );
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

How can I do for use an onclicklistener that do this simple istruction:

```
        sTarga=targhe[position];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By using onitemselected listener you can select item in spinner

```
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String  mselection=spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();    
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "selected "+ mselection, 30).show();              
            /**** do your code*****/
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //  
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

use onItemSelected

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        // your code here
          sTarga=targhe[position];
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        // your code here
    }

});
```